# Speed and direction control of motor by using IR & 555 on Proteus. (Circuit with errors is attached.)

Tags: motor, infrared, 555

[image][image]

I am trying to control motor direction & speed by using IR and 555 on Proteus. Circuit and errors images are attached. Please help me solving this quagmire.

Comment: Have you even tried to calculate your 555 frequency? And why are you using it this way? And if the lower NPN base voltage is clamped to 0.7 volts (and it is, do you know why?) what will that do to the upper base voltage on the other side?

Comment: The error messages simply say that you have not connected any of the CV pins on the 555s.

Comment: As Beast pointed out, you have a problem driving the uppers.

Comment: Have you verified that your modulation frequency works with your receiver? In other words, do you get a response from DQ on U4?

Comment: try giving each transistor its own base resistor rather than having the common on as you do now, tying the control pins (gate, base etc) in an H bridge only really works with mosfets, there's a diode inside the transistor going from the base to ground which will keep the voltage at ~0.7V

Comment: I can't find the ir receiver.

Answer (score 1):

the simulator errors say that the CV pin is unconnected, the datasheet suggests 100nF to ground if you're not going to drive it, in practice this is often unneeded. but it will probably help the simulator.

Your transistor H-Bridge has a problem however, the lower transistors will steal all the base current. the simplest fix it to connect the bases of the upper transistors before the resistor,  the uppers are working as emitter followers and will regulate their own bias current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiixjw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>